# Unicode collation for SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, collation

I need a collation for a database that correctly stores any Unicode character in a SQL Server 2005 instance. The column currently is of type `nvarchar` (can be changed). How can I do that?

Comment: See dba.se for what collation means: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4270/630

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collation has no connection to storage of `N[VAR]CHAR` data - it states the rules of *comparison* between strings.
So - you made the right choice - `NVARCHAR`

Comment: ok, but when I for example store Chinese characters, they show up as "????". Yesterday, I had to store a Hungarian letter 'ő', which is an 'o' with a double acute accent. It got truncated to a reguler 'o', both in the SSMS, and in my application. Then I set the collation to Hungarian, and everything worked fine from then on. So how do I solve this for any string?

Comment: If you store N'ő' and 'ő' - you store different things.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help me. What is the difference between N'ő' and 'ő'? And most of all, how do I solve my original problem, being able to save and retrieve everything correctly, which does NOT work at the moment?

Comment: Use nvarchar type in every piece of your code. In TSQL string in form N'something' - treat as unicode, in form 'something' - as non-unicode ansi string

Comment: To be clear collation only has no connection to storage for `n[var]char`. For `[var]char` it clearly does as it defines the code page.